# Ubuntu 12.04 on Amilo LA1703 after istalling graphics doesn't start?

Tags: 12.04

The installation process pass normal, and after restarting the graphic doesn't start.
It appears message "The system is running in low-graphics mode"
maybe is something connected with the chipset on the laptop VIA Chrome9 HC IGP.
Does someone know fix for this problem with VIA chips, or exact procedure to solve the problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I find a fix for this. It works for me I try it twice. 
So after installing and the message shows all that you have to do is:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg

this works for 12.04 when you have VIA chip VT82xx

In 13.10 is necessity to put the following command when black screen appear:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome

After this the graphic interface is loading.
UnfortunatelyI have another problem guess what? There is no sound on speakers.
I've try everything but didn't get to any success.Please somebody help to decide this problem.
In 12.04 and 13.10 the situation is the same. After installation there is nothing in field play sound through. I think that the system doesn't recognize the sound card at all. Please somebody help.

In 10.10 the sound was correct.